# Como fazer referência ao Assembly no Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Eu estava tentando criar uma aplicação que se conecta com um banco de dados. Mas os métodos de `SqlConnection.Open()`, `SqlConnection.State` e `SqlConnection.Close()` estão com erros todos aparecem a mensagem:

O tipo "Component" está definido em um assembly que não é referenciado, você deve adicionar uma referência ao assembly[...]
[image: Erro]

Comment: Dependências => assemblies => botão direito => adicionar

Comment: Não tem a opção "Adicionar".

Comment: Em dependências deve ter. Em algum lugar precisa ter isso, é só você fazer um esforcinho que acha.

Comment: Achei, mas como saber qual dependência precisa ser adicionada?

Comment: Veja minha resposta

Comment: Já resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Não, eu desisti, criei um novo projeto e esse erro não apareceu mais.

Answer (score 0):

É necessário adicionar o arquivo `System.Data.dl` ao seu projeto.

Clique em dependências, adicionar e escolha o *assembly*.